# undefiened index file

Tags: php, ajax

llevo vaarios dias estancado con esto y aun no he podido resolverlo ,la cosa es que tengo un formulario el cual envio con **ajax** , el formulario cuenta con algunos campos de tipo text y uno de tipo `file` que es mi gran problema he intentado de todas formas y no me quiere reconocer ese input. pero si envio el formulario sin ajax es decir recargando y enviado el formulario directamente a la otra pagina si reconoce el input de tipo `file`.

aqui les dejo lo que he intentado

```
    <form action="ajax/info.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
       <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" />
       <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" />
       <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" />
       <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

      <button type="submit" id="send" form="form">ENVIAR</button>
   </form>
```

**ajax**

```
       $("#form").submit(function(e){

        var form=$("#form");

         var url="ajax/info.php";

          $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    method: 'post',
                    data:  form.serialize(),
                    type:"JSON",
                    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"

  }).done(function(res){

         console.log(res)

  }).fail(function(){

         console.log(res)

    })

              e.preventDefautl();
            })
        })
```

**php**

```
  <?php

   $nombre=$_POST["nomre"];
   $apellido=$_POST["apellido"];
   $correo=$_POST["correo"];
   $destino="";
//intente sin if (isset()) tampoco funciono
  if(isset($_FILES["file"])){

      $file=$_FILES["file"]["name"];

       $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"]
       $destino = "img/" . $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$destino);

  }

echo json_encode(array(

                "nombre"=>$nombre,
                "apellido"=>$apellido,
                "correo"=>$correo,
                "file"=>$file
                     ))

?>
```

en el **output** resivo todos los inputs menos el tipo file,siempre me dice undefined  index file, pero como mencione mas arriva si lo hago directamente sin ajax si lo reconoce. alguna ayuda?

Comment: Me da que ese `form.serialize()`no te esta enviando el fichero

Comment: @JDev cual seria la mejor forma de enviar el fichero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que esta pasando es que intentas enviar el archivo como un campo de texto en ves de como lo que es un archivo de datos, no puedes usar `serialize`, lo que debes uar es `FormDAta`:

```
     $("#form").submit(function(e){

        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'));
         var url="ajax/info.php";

          $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data:  formData,
                    dataType: "json"

  }).done(function(res){

         console.log(res)

  }).fail(function(){

         console.log(res)

    })

              e.preventDefautl();
            })
        })
```

**referencia:**
[Usando Objetos FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData)

Comment: me lanza el siguiente error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: ya lo arregle tenias, algunos parametros mal puestos!